# Call to undefined function get_theme_file_uri() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

im not new to wordpress. I have this problem in my functions.php file. I created an Enqueue styles and Enqueue scripts now upon adding my js files and css files using these code here `get_theme_file_uri` and runs to my server it returns an error like this one

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_theme_file_uri()
```

Now in my other projects that `get_theme_file_uri()` runs well. My server path is like this one for example : `https://test.com/version1` my wordpress is in version1 subfolder in my domain.

Now this is my functions.php script below

```
/**
     * Enqueue scripts
     */
    function theme_scripts(){
        // Deregister default jquery
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

        //Add local jquery
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_script', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/jquery.min.js' ));

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_migrate', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/jquery-migrate.min.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_migrate', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'back_to_top_script', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/back-to-top.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'back_to_top_script', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/smoothScroll.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr_script', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/modernizr.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_cslider', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/jquery.cslider.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'owl_careousel', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/owl.carousel.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/custom.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'app_script', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/app.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'style_switcher', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/style-switcher.js.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'parallax_slider', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/parallax-slider.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'cube_portfolio_script', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/cube-portfolio-lightbox.js' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_parallax', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/jquery.parallax.js' ) );

    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');

    /**
     * Enqueue styles
     */
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
    function theme_styles() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'font_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/css.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/bootstrap.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_min_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'header_default_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/header-default.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'footer_v1_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/footer-v1.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'animate_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/animate.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'animate_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/animate.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'line_icons_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/line-icons.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'font_awesome_styles', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/font-awesome.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'parallax_slider', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/parallax-slider.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'owl_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/owl.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'default_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/default.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'dark_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/dark.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/custom.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'blocks_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/blocks.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'blocks_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/app.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'blocks_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/cubeportfolio.min.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'blocks_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/custom-cubeportfolio.css' ) );

        // Add main style
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_style', get_theme_file_uri( '/style.css' ) );

    }
```

and my header.php file to call that function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html class=" js cssanimations csstransitions" lang="en"><!--<![endif]--><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <head>
        <title><?php wp_title();?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

using the `<?php wp_head(); ?>`

Now can someone help me figured this thing out? why it says

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_theme_file_uri()
```

Any help is muchly appreciated.TIA

Answer (score 0):

use `get_template_directory_uri()`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/

Comment: tried your code it says when i link the css file 
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function get_header()

Comment: files not loaded

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it is so - in documentation all other values are optional for wp_enqueue_style except $handle, but under More Information we can find that safe way is to use all optional values. (it could be related to version and browser cache)

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

When I use get_theme_file_uri() in wp_enqueue_style I'm using all optional parameters wp_enqueue_style function needs - $handle, $src = '', $deps = array(), $ver = false,  $media = 'all'

finally it looks something like

`wp_enqueue_script( 'somename', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/css.css' ), array(), '20181004', false );`